# Getting JSON array value gives errors. I've tried two different ways

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, error, power-automate, flow

I am pulling Office 365 information into a SharePoint Online list and it works fine.

I have a 'Create Item' step for the SPO list and I add metadata from a Parse JSON step like this : `body('Parse_JSON')?['jobTitle']`

But I want to see if the user is Unlicensed.

I have tried both:

```
body('Parse_JSON')?['assignedLicenses'][0]
```

which gives

```
Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Create_item' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language expression 'body('Parse_JSON')?['assignedLicenses'][0]' cannot be evaluated because property '0' cannot be selected. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.
```

and

```
first(body('Parse_JSON')?['assignedLicenses'])
```

which gives

```
One or more fields provided is of type 'Null', a different type is expected.
```

The JSON is like this ...

```
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "aboutMe": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "accountEnabled": {
            "type": "boolean"
        },
        "ageGroup": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "assignedLicenses": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "@@odata.type": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "@@odata.type"
                ]
            }
        },
```

Comment: Where you are using this expression (`first(body('Parse_JSON')?['assignedLicenses'])`)? In "Condition" action?

Comment: Hi Ganesh I am using it directly in my "Create Item" (in the SPO list)

Comment: Which action you are using to get user details? What is the column type in SharePoint where you are passing this value? I don't think you will be able to pass Array directly to SharePoint column values.

Comment: I get user details with the O365 connector Search for Users (v2). Column type is Single line of text.

Comment: Have just tried this but it doesn't create any items now ... https://ibb.co/C7G41wt

Comment: I will try using this action after sometime & will get back to you. I think this property returns null when no license is assigned to user and hence you are facing this error.

Comment: I tried to use empty(body('Parse_JSON')?['assignedLicenses']) but it returns True for everyone. (Licensed or not)

Comment: I tried using this action in flow & I don't see the property you are using in action outputs: `"body": {"value": [{"Id":"4ab30135-cdef-4490-b9gh-1714f4724bb3","AccountEnabled:true","BusinessPhones": [],"CompanyName": "","Country": "IN","Department": "","DisplayName": "G S","GivenName": "Ganesh","JobTitle": "","Mail": "gs@cmpny.com","MailNickname": "gs","PostalCode": "#","Surname": "Sanap","UserPrincipalName": "gs@cmpny.com"}]}` Can you attach screenshot of output of this action from run history if possible?

Comment: Hi Ganesh if I look at the Parse JSON step the schema has assignedLicenses but the content does not.

Comment: I just noticed in my "Get User Profile v2" that I wasn't selecting assignedLicenses.

Comment: I'm still getting True for empty(body('Parse_JSON')?['assignedLicenses'])

Comment: In ParseJSON action, you set the schema (data types). So, it's up to you to provide correct schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the flow I created which will help you with your problem:

[image]

Formula used in compose action:

```
if(greater(length(outputs('Get_user_profile_(V2)')?['body/assignedLicenses']),0),string(outputs('Get_user_profile_(V2)')?['body/assignedLicenses']),'')
```

You can use output of compose action to create a SharePoint list item. One suggestion: use Multiple lines of text in SharePoint list instead of single line of text because output `assignedLicenses` can be more than 255 characters (limitation of single line of text column).

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. I changed the column to multiple lines of text. It just adding blank for the column but the pother columns get data. I can't seem to see the values in the loop as they're greyed out. Maybe I have to wait until the run ends? It usually takes 40 minutes.

Comment: Sure, try using expressions with similar format as given in my answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi Ganesh I get this error ...

Comment: [
  {
    "message": "Required properties are missing from object: @odata.type.",
    "lineNumber": 0,
    "linePosition": 0,
    "path": "assignedLicenses[0]",
    "value": [
      "@odata.type"
    ],
    "schemaId": "#/properties/assignedLicenses/items",
    "errorType": "required",
    "childErrors": []
  },

Comment: {
    "message": "Required properties are missing from object: @odata.type.",
    "lineNumber": 0,
    "linePosition": 0,
    "path": "assignedLicenses[1]",
    "value": [
      "@odata.type"
    ],
    "schemaId": "#/properties/assignedLicenses/items",
    "errorType": "required",
    "childErrors": []
  }
]

Comment: Where do you get this error? Can you add screenshot of current flow you are using and related expressions to your question?